# How to traverse a List of Objects and merge specific value to one big list

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

The title may sound confusing, but I think my problem is a lot simpler.

Here's what I have:

```java
// a List containing `Boat` objects
private final List<Boat> placedBoats;

// each Boat contains a List<Coordinate> which represents a position on a grid
public List<Coordinate> getPosition() {
    return positions;
}
```

Is there a way of how I can use the stream API to merge all `List<Coordinate>` into one big `List<Coordinate>`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think so too, however, I don't now how it would be done. Can you give me a at least a hint?

Comment: Why SPECIFICALLY using Stream API? You can append two lists into one without the overhead of Streams. If you have a filtering criteria, what is it?

Comment: @hfontanez There's no filtering criteria.

Comment: Then why traverse the list? What are you looking for when traversing?

Comment: @hfontanez "What I am looking for?" - One big list with all Coordinate's in it. I thought the stream API might be the simplest way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can do it like this.

- you stream the boats.
- since each boat has a list of coordinates you must flatten those into a common stream
- then collect the coordinates into a list.

```
List<Boat> placedBoats ...;
List<Coordinates> coordinates = placedBoats.stream()
           .flatMap(boat->boat.getCoordinates().stream())
           .toList(); // or .collect(Collectors.toList()) if pre java-16
```

Of course, by doing it as above, the source identity of where the coordinates came from (i.e. the individual boats) is lost.

Answer (score -2):

Possible solution:

```
List<Coordinate> placedBoatCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
for (Boat boat : placedBoats) {
    placedBoatCoordinates.addAll(boat.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Again, explain your problem better. And don't post potential answers to your question. You should either edit your original question or post a new question.

Comment: @hfontanez First, there is nothing wrong with this answer.  It doesn't use streams as suggested but it is still a viable way to do it.  Second, please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @WJS I posted that comment before the problem was clarified. I know anyone can answer their own question. What I stated is that POTENTIAL answers should not be posted as they might not be a good answer. That is different than implying you cannot answer your own question. In fact, I was the first one who asked why use streams API specifically when you could accomplish the same without it.